# Display a fix number of row item depending on screen size using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a web page where a number of items are displayed. Suppose there are 14 items to show.

Each item has a bootstrap column configuration depending on type of device screen size. That's easy with bootstrap by just adding the following classes `col-lg-2`, `col-md-3`, `col-sm4`, and `col-xs-6`, such that there are respectively 6, 4, 3 and 2 items per row.

I'm using bootstrap `data-toggle`, `data-target` and `collapse` classes in order to have 2 full row of items and the rest hidden.

For example, on a `lg` device screen, the code is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item1</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item2</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item3</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item4</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item5</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item6</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item7</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item8</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item9</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item10</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item11</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item12</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 hide-this collapse">item13</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 hide-this collapse">item14</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".hide-this">Toggle</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case there are 12 visible items and only 2 items are hidden.

For a `md` device there are 8 visible items and 6 hidden items:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item1</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item2</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item3</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item4</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item5</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item6</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item7</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item8</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 hide-this collapse">item9</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 hide-this collapse">item10</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 hide-this collapse">item11</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 hide-this collapse">item12</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 hide-this collapse">item13</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 hide-this collapse">item14</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".hide-this">Toggle</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the `sm` devices, there are 6 visible items and 8 hidden, and at last, for `xs` devices there are 2 visible items and 12 hidden.

While these code snippets work fine on each device screen separately, I have no idea how I could combine them all together.

My goal is to have only 2 rows of visible items and the rest hidden whatever number of items or screen config. So for I'm looking for a way to dynamically add the `hide-this collapse` classes to a number of items based on the screen configuration.

Any idea is very welcome!

Remarks:

- Assume there are always at least 12 items to show in order to have full rows to display in all screen config
- I'm using bootstrap 3 (but bootstrap 4 would be an option if that would easier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect screen size, use [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/docs/#mq). The `mq()` function allows to query media property (e.g. screen size). Note the pixel dimension 768, 992, 1200 which maps to `sm`, `md`, `lg` min size.

Use [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) CSS property with `n+x` parameter (x=3,7,9,13)in order to skip the first elements.

In the `documment.ready()` javascript function, update the `div` elements to add the bootstrap class `collapse` and `hide-this` to get the toggle button behavior.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<html>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item1</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item2</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item3</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item4</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item5</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item6</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item7</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item8</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item9</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item10</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item11</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item12</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item13</div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">item14</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".hide-this">Toggle</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width:767px)')){
            $('.row div:nth-child(n+3)').addClass("collapse hide-this");
    }
    if (Modernizr.mq('(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px)')){
            $('.row div:nth-child(n+7)').addClass("collapse hide-this");
    }
    if (Modernizr.mq('(min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px)')){
            $('.row div:nth-child(n+9)').addClass("collapse hide-this");
    }
    if (Modernizr.mq('(min-width:1200px)')){
            $('.row div:nth-child(n+13)').addClass("collapse hide-this");
    }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using media queries. You can give your items classes that are affected by the current screen width with media queries.

Example:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .md-hide {
         display: none;
    }
}
```

this will give the CSS-property `display: none;` to all items with the `md-hide` class, as long as the width is smaller than or equal to 1200px (which is bootstrap's breaking point between "md" and "lg").

UPDATE:

if you want to be able to toggle the visibility using your button, you can use Javascript to change the `data-target` of the toggle button like so:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    var target = '.lg-hide';
    if (window.innerWidth <= 1200) {
        target = target + ', .md-hide';
    }
    if (window.innerWidth <= 992) {
        target = target + ', .sm-hide';
    }
    // you would need to give a specific ID to the toggle button
    document.getElementById('#togglebtn').setAttribute('data-target', target);
}
```

I'd be happy to hear if it works, plain Javascript isn't my biggest forte :D

Comment: thanks for this, but how this can be linked to the toggle button?

Comment: Do you want the toggle-button to toggle the visibility of the items with the "hide-this"-class?